# Bluetooth headphone range issues

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, bluetooth-speaker

I have a unique issue with [my bluetooth headset from Sony](https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=DRBTN200) and [my System76 ServalWS machine](https://system76.com/laptops/serval). I am running a fresh installation of Ubuntu 15.04.

I am able to connect the headset fine, even select the HD audio instead of Telephony Duplex. My issue is that my head must be within ~20 inches from the machine at all times, with my head turned to the left, so that the right earphone is pointing towards the machine, otherwise the audio will be terribly jumpy (0.1-2 second break in audio every 0.5-1.5 seconds of clean audio).

Is this a hardware issue with my laptop? I can connect my headset to my android phone and listen to uninterrupted audio for up to about 10 meters through two walls, so it's not the headset.

Is there anything I can do to improve this so I can listen to audio within at least 3 feet of my computer with my head turned in any orientation. Is is possible this is a software issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was faulty hardware. Tried it after installing Windows and had the same issue. Installing and using a bluetooth dongle fixed my issue.